# RestKit pathpatterns including IDs

Tags: ios, restkit-0.20

So the problem is that when I'm trying to load entity from [here](http://dealer-app.net/api/cars/2/features.json?auth_token=Mg7Kd7pb1CG9dBZmx4Q9) I'm not getting things to work. My Pathpatterns seems to be wrong.
Here's my Mapping and Descriptor:

```
RKEntityMapping *statsMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Stat" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];

[statsMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"sort_id" : @"sortID",
 @"id" : @"statID",
 @"deleted" : @"deletedFlag",
 @"created_at": @"createdAt",
 @"updated_at": @"updatedAt"
 }];
statsMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"statID" ];
[statsMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"title"]];


RKEntityMapping *featuresMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Feature" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];

[featuresMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"sort_id" : @"sortID",
 @"id" : @"featureID",
 @"deleted" : @"deletedFlag",
 @"created_at": @"createdAt",
 @"updated_at": @"updatedAt",
 }];
featuresMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"featureID" ];
[featuresMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"title", @"value"]];
[statsMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"features" toKeyPath:@"features" withMapping:featuresMapping]];

RKResponseDescriptor *statsDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:statsMapping
                                                                                  pathPattern: @"/api/cars/:carID/features.json"
                                                                                      keyPath:nil
                                                                                  statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[objectManager addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:@[newsDescriptor, catalogDescriptor, statsDescriptor]];
```

So when I use pathPattern:nil it works, but if no answer is returned by url it just tries to put another responsedescriptor to the response and gives me random data :)

The question is, if I have the car ID in the middle of the pattern, how should I declare it?

Thank you!

Edit1: This is how I do request:

```
    - (void)getStats:(NSNumber *)carID
    {
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"api/cars/%@/features.json", carID]
                                           parameters:@{@"auth_token" : [Constants authToken]}
                                              success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                                                  RKLogInfo(@"Load complete: Stats loaded");
                                              }
                                              failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                                  RKLogError(@"Load failed with error: %@", error);
                                                  [self showError:error withDelay:3];
                                              }];
}
```

Comment: Your path pattern of @"/api/cars/:carID/features.json" looks ok. How are you making the request? And when using that path pattern are you getting no mapping done at all?

Comment: As I said, when I use this descriptor with pathPattern:nil everything is ok, and mapped fine, but I don't want to use this way.

Comment: Turn on trace logging and see what it says: `RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelTrace);`

Comment: Been there, did that. It says: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Stat 0xd5cfbf0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity (null) is not key value coding-compliant for the key "updatedAt".'

Comment: http://pastebin.com/DWCa4dfx - whole tracelog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your trace log there is some problem with your managed objects, not your mappings. Your entities are obviously defined in the model and with the correct names and with the appropriate attributes. So it looks like either you created classes for the entities but wrongly or that the object manager isn't being provided with an / the correct object store reference.

---

Your log contains `CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Stat'` and `[<Stat 0xa68b7c0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity (null) is not key value coding-compliant for the key "statID".` which are both issues to do with the entity creation / referencing. It isn't clear how that happens based on the code posted.

Try changing your path pattern to remove the leading slash:

```
@"api/cars/:carID/features.json"
```

when defining your `statsDescriptor` as that can cause the pattern to not match.

Comment: I have doubts on that because of 2 facts: my entities work great if I do not use pathPattern. All other descriptors also work great, so it is not a store reference unfortunately.

Comment: Did that, now it says: <RKResponseDescriptor: 0xa668830 baseURL=http://dealer-app.net pathPattern=api/cars/:carID/features.json statusCodes=200-299> failed to match: response path '/api/cars/2/features.json?auth_token=Mg7Kd7pb1CG9dBZmx4Q9' did not match the path pattern 'api/cars/:carID/features.json'., NSLocalizedDescription=No response descriptors match the response loaded., keyPath=null, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://dealer-app.net/api/cars/2/features.json?auth_token=Mg7Kd7pb1CG9dBZmx4Q9, NSUnderlyingError=0xa2a7630 "No mappable object representations were found at the key paths searched."}

Comment: Then the slash is required and I'm currently at a loss to explain what you're seeing. Are you using the latest version of the master / development branch?

Comment: Sure I do, I just have worries about this /:carID/ guy. I replaced it with /2/ but nothing helps for now (

Comment: Do you have other response descriptors which also use path patterns, or which use a `nil` path pattern? What are they?

Comment: well eventually I checked all paths and it turned out that it uses 2 '/' instead of one... How stupid of me